# During a Sugar Crush are the candies chosen random?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

At the end of candy crush, if you have moves remaining you get a "Sugar Crush". This is where some candies that are chosen on the board change to special candies. I was wondering if the candies chosen had any pattern.

More specifically, are there any rules that stop two candies forming next to each other, to maximize points. For example if two Wrapped Candies spawned next to each other, there area would be less then if they spawned somewhere else on the board.

Also, during the "Sugar Crush" are the colors picked by a Color Bomb random, or do they have a pattern, such as choosing the color directly above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *good* answer would require referencing some official statement or a technical documentation, and I doubt one exists. One reason for King not to disclose this information could be that they don't need disputes raised by unhappy users who disagree with how the random events occur (for example, how stupid Jelly Fish chooses where to float, completely ignoring the ticking bombs, <s>which I hate the most</s>).

**Anyway: no promise, no responsibility,** and this must be the only possible answer.

From personal (and therefore, inherently inaccurate) observation, in CC Saga, it seems to be completely random, while in CC Soda, the Color Bomb has greater (yet not 100%) chance to prefer the color of a candy directly above it (or the color of a striped/wrapped candy that hits the Color Bomb).